# PayPal errors with 'Unspecified Method' on a valid METHOD argument (error code 81002)

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to integrate the PayPal's in-context express checkout experience and I am stuck at this error.
Here is the code I am testing out:

```
axios
  .post(
    "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp",
    {
      USER: process.env.PAYPAL_USER,
      PWD: process.env.PAYPAL_PASSWORD,
      SIGNATURE: process.env.PAYPAL_SIGNATURE,
      METHOD: "SetExpressCheckout",
      VERSION: "124.0",
      PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE: "USD",
      PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT: "4.5",
      RETURNURL: "http://localhost:3000/pay",
      PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID:
        "sb-47jx7i2598580@business.example.com",
    },
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/url-form-encoded",
      },
    }
  )
    .then((res) => {
      console.log("Got res", res.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("Caught err", err);
    });
```

Can somebody help me spot the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That API is at least a couple generations out of date, why not use orders V2 'Set Up Transaction' and 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

Comment: @Preson PHX, Can I achieve parallel payment i.e. user to user payment with the Orders API?

Comment: You can have a user to user payment, with the `payee` variable https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/custom-payee/ , but not multiple in parallel

Comment: I've been looking for info like this forever. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out: the content type is all wrong and the post data needs a different encoding which I achieved using `qs` package.

```
axios.post(
  "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp",
  qs.stringify({
    USER: process.env.PAYPAL_USER,
    PWD: process.env.PAYPAL_PASSWORD,
    SIGNATURE: process.env.PAYPAL_SIGNATURE,
    METHOD: "SetExpressCheckout",
    VERSION: "124.0",
    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE: "USD",
    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT: "4.5",
    RETURNURL: "http://localhost:3000/pay",
    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID:
      "sb-47jx7i2598580@business.example.com",
  }),
  {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-url-encoded", // right one!
    },
  }
)
.then((res) => {
  console.log("Got res", res.data);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.error("Caught err", err);
});
```